# How to call a layout inside the linear layout after clicking the buttons?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning android and And I'm facing some troubles. I kindly request you to solve these problems.

I have 2 linear layouts inside a linear layout, both are placed horizontally. The left side section contains some buttons and if we click the button the respective layout must come on the right-side section. As of now, if I click the button the specific layout is appearing but not inside the second linear layout. And also, I want to set a default layout to appear on the right side layout. For ex, here I've added the "breakfastdishes.xml", which I want as a default right-side layout, and when I click on the buttons from the left-side layout, according to id the right-side layout must change. Can you please help me to achieve it?

Here is my code:

**MenuSection.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MenuSection"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:padding="10dp">



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/breakfast"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:text="@string/breakfast"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_category"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#AC8E0D"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lunch"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:text="@string/lunch"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_category"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#0A5FAA"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eveningSnacks"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menu_category"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="@string/snacks"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="#DF5124" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dinner"
                    android:layout_width="220dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:text="@string/dinner"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_category"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:backgroundTint="#14A61A"/>

            </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemsDisplay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menuDispArea"
            android:layout_width="508dp"
            android:layout_height="412dp">

<!--            <include-->
<!--                layout="@layout/breakfastdishes"-->
<!--                android:layout_width="508dp"-->
<!--                android:layout_height="412dp" />-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**BreakfastDishes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:paddingStart="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/burger"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="102dp"
            android:layout_x="10dp"
            android:layout_y="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/burger_breakfast" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/burgerTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/burger"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/burger"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/burger"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/burger"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/burger"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eggOmlet"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:layout_x="233dp"
            android:layout_y="7dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/egg_omlet" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eggOmletTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eggOmlet"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/eggOmlet"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/eggOmlet"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/eggOmlet"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/eggOmlet"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MenuSection.java**

```
package com.example.restaurant;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MenuSection extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_section);

        Button breakfast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.breakfast);
        Button lunch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lunch);

        breakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuSection.this, BreakfastDishes.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        lunch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MenuSection.this, LunchDishes.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akshay, here are a few things you have to keep in mind ;

1. In the button click listener you are launching new activity instead of updating
   the existing layout. When you use `Intent` it will launch new activity and
   close the current activity. So in your case **do not** use `startActivity`
2. Use `findViewById` for the `menuDispArea` layout and add update
   the content when user clicks on the button.
3. never use `dp` for text size, use `sp`
4. you can divide the layout using LinearLayout weights to split your layouts on
   all the devices instead of hardcoding the height and width

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight

edit: Added sample

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MenuSection.this);

LinearLayout parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.menuDispArea);

View menuLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.BreakfastDishes, parentLayout, false);

parentLayout.addView(menuLayout);
```

You can use this to inflate any XML in your layout dynamically. Make sure you are doing this inside button onClick for your use case.

Comment: Hello Sahitya,  Thanks for the answer. But I didn't understand the first point you have mentioned. Can you please mention one line code here?